# C++ switch statement for arithmetic operations

Tags: c++, math, arithmetic-expressions

When I run my program, it doesn't allow me to pick an operation.  It just goes straight to "Invalid option" and asks again.  I want to be able to choose '+', '-', '*', '/', '^', and '!' as my options. What did I do wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

char operation;
int num1, num2, result, remain;

//Display the menu to the user and get their first choice

    cout << "What operation would you like to perform:" << endl 
    << " + addition\n - subtraction\n * multiplication\n / division\n ^ number to power\n ! factorial" 
    << "\n q quit" << endl << endl << "Operation? ";
    cin >> operation;

//Switch - the user does not want to quit

switch (operation)
{

case 1: result=num1+num2;
    cout << "Enter the first number to add: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the second number to add: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << endl << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << result;
    break;

case 2: result=num1-num2;
    cout << "Enter the first number to subtract: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the second number to subtract: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << endl << num1 << " - " << num2 << " = " << result;
    break;

case 3: result=num1*num2;
    cout << "Enter the first number to multiply: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the second number to multiply: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << endl << num1 << " * " << num2 << " = " << result;
    break;

case 4: result=num1/num2;
    cout << "Enter the dividend: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the divisor: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << endl << num1 << " / " << num2 << " = " << result;
    cout << endl << num1 << " % " << num2 << " = " << result;
    break;

case 5: result=num1^num2;
    cout << "Enter the base number " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the power: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << endl << num1 << " ^ " << num2 << " = " << result;
    break;

case 6: result=num1!=num2;
    cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << endl << num1 << " ! " << " = " << result;
    break;

default: 
    cout << "That is an invalid operation!" << endl;    
    break;

} // switch statement closed

cout << endl << "What operation would you like to perform:" << endl << " + addition\n - subtraction\n * multiplication\n / division\n ^ number to power\n ! factorial" << "\n q quit" << endl << endl << "Operation? ";
cin >> operation; 

return 0;
} //main statement closed
```

Comment: `case 1`? Shouldn't it rather be `case '+'`? You are matching a `char` (operation) with `int` values.

Comment: Oh. Okay.  The way my professor explained it was that each case could be labeled in order.  That makes more sense.  I'll try that.

Comment: @Liz Your computations all come in a wrong place, too.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That helped. and at the end when I ask if it wants to do another operation, it just ends even if I pick an operation.  Is that because my final cout statement is in the wrong place too?

Comment: @Liz Please see the edit. If this solves your problem, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey checkmark next to it. This will tell other site visitors that the problem is solved, and earn you a badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a `char` against a switch of `int`s that do not match character codes that you wish to select. If you would like to decide among characters, use character *literals* instead of integer numbers:

```
case '+':
    // Read inputs first
    cout << "Enter the first number to add: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter the second number to add: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    // Compute the result next
    result=num1+num2;
    cout << endl << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << result;
    break;
```

Note that the assignment

```
result=num1+num2;
```

should come *after* the code that reads the inputs, i.e. `num1` and `num2`.

> at the end when I ask if it wants to do another operation, it just ends even if I pick an operation.

This is because an end-of-line character that you entered after `num2` is sitting in the buffer. You need to ignore it. Add this line:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

before

```
cin >> operation;
```